# Sequence solves inequalities

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Suppose $Q(D)$ is a Markov chain with state space $E= \{0,1,...\}$. Further the transition matrix of $Q(D)$ is given by:
$$P_D=\begin{pmatrix}
\delta_0 & \delta_1 & \delta_2 & \delta_3 &  ...\\
\delta_0 & \delta_1 & \delta_2 & \delta_3 &  ... \\
0 & \delta_0 & \delta_1 & \delta_2 & ...\\
0 & 0 &  \delta_0 & \delta_1 & ...\\
&&&&...
\end{pmatrix}$$
where 
$$
\delta_j=\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{(\lambda S)^j}{j!} e^{-\lambda S} \right]
$$
and $S$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{E}[S]=\frac{1}{\lambda}.$

Then in my book it is written, that it is not dificult to see the following claim. But that is not so obvious for me. Can somebody help me out?

> Claim: $\{ y_j : j \geq 1 \}$, where $y_j$ is given by $y_j=j$ for $j \geq 1$, solves the following inequalities:
>   $$y_j \geq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_{ij} y_j , \text{ for } i \geq 1.$$

If I take for example $i=1$, then I get:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_{1j} y_j=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_{1j} j=p_{11} 1+p_{12} 2+p_{13} 3+...=\delta_1 + 2 \delta_2 +3 \delta_3+...$$

So I have to prove that this less or equal 1, but why? If I would get that step, then I think I would get if for the particular case. ( By the way, since it is a transition matrix, we also know that $\sum_j \delta_j$=1.)

Can anybody help me? I appreciate any idea, help or advice!

Thank you so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\delta_1 + 2 \delta_2 +3 \delta_3+\cdots=\sum_{j\geqslant1}j\,\delta_j=\sum_{j\geqslant1}j\,E\left[\frac{(\lambda S)^j}{j!} e^{-\lambda S} \right]=\sum_{i\geqslant0}E\left[\frac{(\lambda S)^{i+1}}{i!} e^{-\lambda S} \right]=E\left[\lambda S\right]$$

Comment: thank you so much!! That s perfect!